# Vue js return wrong datetime from Laravel/MySQL DB

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I don't know why, but when I display the datetime from a DB record in Vue JS, it's not the same datetime from the DB record.

Just before sending the records to the vue, I looked with the `DD` function if the records has the right datetime and everything is correct.

But when I'm looking at the record into the vue with a console.log in the mounted hook, it shows the datetime with like 4 more hours..

```
In DB record I get:  2022-10-31 21:30:00

In Vue js template I get: 2022-10-31 1:30:00
```

Why is that? I tried `moment.js` to try to format it, but it doesn't work. I can't find anything about this.

But when I do `console.log(new Date)` it's giving me the good datetime.

It seems like the vue's changing my datetime somehow.

The datetime from MySQL is just the datetime `created_at` columns from laravel when storing data.

Here's my vue js template, nothing special

```
<template>

    <AppLayout title="Alerte">
        <template #header>
            <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
                Alerte
            </h2>
        </template>
        <div class="content-table pb-5">
            <!--Section 1-->
            <div class="grid grid-cols-12 m-0">
                <div class="col-span-12 p-1">
                    <div class="section flex items-center flex-row bg-white">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor"
                            class="bi bi-bell-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path
                                d="M8 16a2 2 0 0 0 2-2H6a2 2 0 0 0 2 2zm.995-14.901a1 1 0 1 0-1.99 0A5.002 5.002 0 0 0 3 6c0 1.098-.5 6-2 7h14c-1.5-1-2-5.902-2-7 0-2.42-1.72-4.44-4.005-4.901z" />
                        </svg>
                        <div class="title-section flex flex-col">
                            <span>Liste des alertes</span>
                            <span>Géré vos alertes selon la page</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid grid-cols-12 m-0">
                <div class="col-span-12 p-1">
                    <div class="section justify-center flex items-center flex-col bg-white relative">
                        <div class="flex mt-4 items-center flex-row justify-center">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" fill="currentColor"
                                v-if="alerts.actives.length > 0" class="bi bi-exclamation-triangle" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                <path
                                    d="M7.938 2.016A.13.13 0 0 1 8.002 2a.13.13 0 0 1 .063.016.146.146 0 0 1 .054.057l6.857 11.667c.036.06.035.124.002.183a.163.163 0 0 1-.054.06.116.116 0 0 1-.066.017H1.146a.115.115 0 0 1-.066-.017.163.163 0 0 1-.054-.06.176.176 0 0 1 .002-.183L7.884 2.073a.147.147 0 0 1 .054-.057zm1.044-.45a1.13 1.13 0 0 0-1.96 0L.165 13.233c-.457.778.091 1.767.98 1.767h13.713c.889 0 1.438-.99.98-1.767L8.982 1.566z" />
                                <path
                                    d="M7.002 12a1 1 0 1 1 2 0 1 1 0 0 1-2 0zM7.1 5.995a.905.905 0 1 1 1.8 0l-.35 3.507a.552.552 0 0 1-1.1 0L7.1 5.995z" />
                            </svg>
                            <div class="title-section flex flex-col mr-3 ml-3 relative">
                                <span class="flex">Alerte(s) en cours <p v-if="alerts.actives.length > 0" class="ml-1">[{{ alerts.actives.length }}]</p></span>
                                <span>Toutes les alertes présentement en cours</span>
                                <div
                                    class="top-[11px] left-[205px] animate-ping absolute inline-flex h-2 w-2 rounded-full bg-red-400 opacity-75">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mt-5 mb-5 !ml-0 w-full md:w-[700px] max-h-[250px] overflow-y-auto hide-scrollbar static">
                            <div class="custom-gradian absolute w-full md:w-[700px] h-[75px] bottom-0 z-10">
                            </div>
                            <div v-if="alerts.actives.length > 0">
                                <div v-for="alert in alerts.actives" :key="alert.id"
                                    class="cursor-pointer my-2 py-5 px-3 border rounded-md mr-[10px] flex items-center flex-col sm:flex-row"
                                    :class="{ 'border-red-400': (alert.degree === 3), 'bg-red-50': (alert.degree === 3), 'border-yellow-400': (alert.degree === 2), 'bg-yellow-50': (alert.degree === 2), 'border-black': (alert.degree === 1), 'bg-slate-100': (alert.degree === 1) }">
                                    <div> <!--Animate flashing-->
                                        <Exclamation :nb="alert.degree" :size="25" class="animate-fade"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ml-3 flex justify-between items-center flex-col-reverse sm:flex-row w-full">
                                        <span>{{ alert.description }}</span>
                                        <span class="min-w-[135px] ml-0 my-2 sm:ml-3" :class="{ 'text-red-400': (alert.degree === 3),'text-yellow-400': (alert.degree === 2), 'text-slate-400': (alert.degree === 1) }">[{{ alert.created_at }}]</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div v-else class="p-2 text-center border rounded-md">
                                <span>Aucune alerte pour le moment</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="grid grid-cols-12 m-0">
                <div class="col-span-12 p-1">
                    <div class="section flex flex-col bg-white">
                        <div class="mt-4 flex items-center flex-row justify-center">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="40" height="40" fill="currentColor"
                                class="bi bi-journal-text" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                <path
                                    d="M5 10.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h2a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-2a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-2a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-2a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-2a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5z" />
                                <path
                                    d="M3 0h10a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v12a2 2 0 0 1-2 2H3a2 2 0 0 1-2-2v-1h1v1a1 1 0 0 0 1 1h10a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V2a1 1 0 0 0-1-1H3a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v1H1V2a2 2 0 0 1 2-2z" />
                                <path
                                    d="M1 5v-.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0V5h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-2a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1H1zm0 3v-.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0V8h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-2a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1H1zm0 3v-.5a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0v.5h.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-2a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1H1z" />
                            </svg>
                            <div class="title-section flex flex-col mr-3 ml-3">
                                <span>Historique d'alertes</span>
                                <span>Liste de toute les alertes selon la page</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="header mb-4 mt-4 mr-5 flex flex-row justify-center">
                            <div class="flex flex-col ml-3 mr-3 w-[280px]">
                                <span class="text-light-gray text-xs">Page</span>
                                <select v-model="selectedPage" @change="changeTable"
                                    class="w-full border-[1px] border-gray-50 rounded-md shadow-md focus:ring-0 hover:cursor-pointer">
                                    <option v-for="page in pages" :value="page">{{ page }}</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pb-5">
                            <div class="max-h-[500px] max-w-[950px] overflow-y-auto m-auto">
                                <AlertTable :alerts="selectedAlerts"></AlertTable>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </AppLayout>

</template>
<script>
import AppLayout from "@/Layouts/AppLayout.vue";
import SectionBorder from '@/Components/SectionBorder.vue';
import Exclamation from '@/Components/Custom/Exclamation.vue';

import AlertTable from '@/Pages/Components/Alert/AlertTable.vue';

export default {
    components: {
        AppLayout,
        SectionBorder,
        AlertTable,
        Exclamation
    }, data() {
        return {
            pages: ['Machine', 'Inspection', 'Sensor'],
            selectedPage: '',
            selectedAlerts: []
        }
    }, props: {
        alerts: Object,
    }, methods: {
        changeTable() {
            if (this.selectedPage === "Sensor") this.selectedAlerts = this.alerts.sensor;
            if (this.selectedPage === "Machine") this.selectedAlerts = this.alerts.machine;
            if (this.selectedPage === "Inspection") this.selectedAlerts = this.alerts.inspection;
        }
    }, mounted() {
        this.selectedAlerts = this.alerts.sensor;
        this.selectedPage = 'Sensor';
    }
}
</script>
<style>
table {
    border-collapse: separate !important;
    border-spacing: 5px 10px !important;
}
</style>
```

Thank you!

Comment: It might be a timezone issue on your frontend. Please add the code related to your question. So, someone can understand the specific issue and assist you :)

Comment: could you show how you are trying to show on front end?

Comment: Its done! But there's nothing special

Answer (score 0):

maybe the problem with timezone.suggest to use timestamp as usual.and then use   moment-timezone to format it.
for example:

```
import moment from 'moment-timezone';
moment.tz.setDefault('utc');
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work!